# Can a CSPRNG, seeded with a key, be used to generate a byte sequence as long as the plaintext to XOR it with that?

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator, xor

Given a “safe” (meaning: brute-force is your only shot) cryptographically strong PRNG, wouldn't it be safe to encrypt data using the CSPRNG to create a key as long as the data and then encrypt the data by XORing it with the key?

Comment: We call that a (synchronous) stream cipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would.

As CodesinChaos reminded us in [his comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53251/encryption-using-cs-prng#comment117838_53251):

> We call that a (synchronous) stream cipher.

Look up RC4 and A5/1, two of the most statistically popular ciphers in the universe.  Also compare to a correctly generated one time pad.  Not a lot else to say at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The only secure-proven encryption scheme is the one-time-pad. That uses a key of plaintext-length for XOR-encryption once, else it is broken. If your CS-PRNG is not breakable, in sence of any attacker is able to win the predictable game, it is close to being a OTP.

Now think about you would like to encrypt a branch of Wikipedia. How would you like to (1) store and (2) transport the key secure? How would you make sure that no key is used twice?